# Cannot save docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, server

To start off, I am new to docker.
I am running docker on a ubuntu server.

I created a new container using

```
 sudo docker run -ti --rm ubuntu /bin/bash
```

but when I try to save

```
root@fb3811666c85:/# docker commit -p fb3811666c85 mycontainer
```

I get

```
bash: docker: command not found
```

I also tried

```
root@fb3811666c85:/# sudo docker commit -p fb3811666c85 mycontainer
```

and got

```
sudo: docker: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using `docker commit` at all is almost never a best practice.  Docker's [Containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial could be a good starting point for building a reproducible image from a Dockerfile, which you can check into source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is not run from within the container. (Your container doesn't have docker, so the error is obvious. But even if it had docker, it wouldn't achieve the result that you are seeking. Might probably complain about the container being not available. If you are using the host socket, then it might not happen).

In one terminal open a container, make changes that you want.
In second terminal, run docker ps. Copy the container id. Run the command.
In your command, instead of myContainer, I think you'd want to use myImage:myNewTag.